# Why does the government formation process tend to be so fast in Denmark?

Tags: parties, cabinet, denmark

In Denmark, the government formation process after each general election tends to be extremely fast by European standard.

In fact, the last government formation only took 20 days after the 2019 general election, and that was the longest negotiation since 1988.

Some might argue that this is because Denmark uses "[negative parliamentarianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politics_of_Denmark#Tradition_of_minority_governments)" - a process which dictates that the Cabinet can remain in office as long as there is no majority against it.

However, that is not the case in other countries that also use negative parliamentarianism. For Iceland, the [last negotiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017_Icelandic_parliamentary_election#Government_formation) took a month. While in Sweden, the negotiation tends to be longer, so much so that the [last one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_Swedish_general_election#Government_formation) took 4 months.

So what is so special about Denmark's post-election negotiation processes? Are Danes just more consensus oriented people?

And yes, I've watched S1E2 of [Borgen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OKduYvZ1TYo), but I still don't fully understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The biggest difference to e.g. Germany is that the minor parties declare loyalty to either the left (red) or the right (blue) wing before the election. And part of the election is then that voters both vote for a party, and their known loyalty.

Within the left or right block there could also be a debate about who gets to lead government, but that has been trivial based on the biggest party for many years.

This means that once the election is done then you know who the prime minister is. So the negotiation can skip the step with this.

The negotiation then only needs to focus on who of the supporting parties should be part of government, and writing the paper that is the foundation for the government.

Comment: "The negotiation then only needs to focus on who of the supporting parties should be part of government" - There aren't any question of what part of each parties manifesto is to be taken forward? Or is that the foundation paper?

Comment: The paper is a standard paper that both have guidelines, and sometimes also promises.  But promises can be broken and the paper is not governed by any law. Danish politics is fairly predicable so e.g. you know that if you want a law that is "hard on immigration" then people know what parties support that and the bill will be done with those parties from the red and blue side instead of the parties supporting the government.